# Can´t create iOS projects with Cocos 3D, only Mac projects

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I install Cocos 2D and Cocos 3D.

I can create Cocos 2D projects, but I can´t create Cocos 3D projects.
 I select Cocos 3D in iOS section, but the created project is for MAC. 
 Why ??

I can´t solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cocos3D is for Mac only, and it only works with cocos2d v1.x. It may not work with the very latest version v1.1 of cocos2d, so you might want to try the v1.0.1 stable version instead.

In any case you have to re-install the cocos2d & cocos3d templates if you used a different version.